# React avoid reload of component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We have a dropdownlist which is populated by a get request to backend.
The dropdownlist contains certain possible filters.
ie: client number and type.

When I select something in one of the DDLs i want to keep the selected value I think it is refreshing the whole page.

So I have two get requests one for populating the main content-area called "ExportView"
and the other for fetching the filter values.

Sending the function to filter and fetch new data for the main content section as a parameter to searchfield section.

I have tried to set event.preventDefault() in the handlefilter function. Tried to use usecallback hook also, but no luck.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL + "exports?take=10&"+ filterExportType + filterClientNumber).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setLoadedExports(data);
});
}, [filterClientNumber, filterExportType]);


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL + "exports/filterselection").then((response) => 
    {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        setLoadedFilters(data);
    });
}, []);


const handleFilter = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.name === "exportType")
    {
        if(event.target.value === "")
        {
            setFilterExportType();
        }
        else {
            setFilterExportType("&exportTypeId=" + event.target.value);
        } 
    }
    if(event.target.name === "client")
    {
        if(event.target.value === "")
        {
            setFilterClientNumber("");
        }
        else {
            setFilterClientNumber("&clientNumber=" + event.target.value);
        }
    }
},[]);

if(isLoading)
{
    return (
        <section>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </section>
    );
}

return(
    <>
       <SearchField handleFilter={handleFilter} selection={loadedFilters}/> 
        <ExportView data={loadedExports}/>
    </>
)
```

EDIT:
Added Searchfield component for reference:

```
    function SearchField(props)
{
      const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState('');
      const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState(''); 
      console.log("rerender");
      if(!props.selection.clientNumbers)
      {
            return (
                  <p>Loading...</p>
            )
      }
    return (
          <form>
           <select value={selectedClient} className="clientSelection" name="client" onChange={(event) => {
                  setSelectedClient(event.target.value);
                 props.handleFilter(event);
            }}>
                  <option key={0} value=''></option>
            {
                  props.selection.clientNumbers.map((client, index) => 
                        <option key={index + 1} value={client}>{client}</option>    
                  )
            }    
            </select>
            <select value={selectedType} name="exportType" onChange={(event) => 
                  {
                        setSelectedType(event.target.value);
                       props.handleFilter(event); 
                  }}>
                        <option key={0} value=''></option>
            {
                  props.selection.exportTypes.map((exportType, index) => 
                        <option key={index +1 } value={exportType.id}>{exportType.description}</option>    
                  )
            }    
            </select>
          </form>
      );
}
export default SearchField;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
   if(isLoading)
   {
      return (
        <section>
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </section>
      );
   }
```

Every time your first effect runs you will set loading to true and it will rerender whole content and display only loader. In that effect you are having `[filterClientNumber, filterExportType]` as dependecy, and inside `handleFilter` you are changing state thus forcing effect to execute every time `handleFilter` is being called - and because of this you will end up only with loader on the screen each time you call `handleFilter`. Your solution would be to move loader down and to have something like this:

```
return(
<>
   <SearchField handleFilter={handleFilter} selection={loadedFilters}/> 
   {
    isLoading &&  
      <section>
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </section> ||
      <ExportView data={loadedExports}/>
    }
</>
```

)

Like this filter section will always be on the screen, and loader will be displayed only in one part of the interface while loading data with new filters. Like this you will avoid that fake effect of reloading whole-page, because it really does not make sense to hide all content on page while loading data, especially when you have filters which trigger data to (re)load.

Comment: I think you are correct, I have been struggeling with this for some time. 
I added a two states also to the Searchfield component to handle the set value in the ddls.

I'll add that file for reference as well.